# using isin() for a column that has list values

Tags: python, pandas

I have two dataframes. Dataframe A has a column that consists of `list` values of ids (named items). Dataframe B has a column of `int` values of ids (named id).

Dataframe A:

```
date       |    items
2019-06-05 | [121, 123, 124]
2019-06-06 | [109, 125]
2019-06-07 | [108, 126]
```

Dataframe B:

```
name  | id
item1 | 121
item2 | 122
item3 | 123
item4 | 124
item5 | 125
item6 | 126
```

I want to filter the Dataframe A and keep only the rows that all values of `items` in that row exist in the `id` column of Dataframe B.

Based on the above example, the result should be:

Dataframe C:

```
date       |    items
2019-06-05 | [121, 123, 124]
```

(since Dataframe B doesn't have rows with id==108 and id==109)

If `items` was a `int` column, I could use:

```py
dataframe_a[dataframe_a.items.isin(dataframe_b.id)]
```

How can I achieve this in `list` columns?

Answer (score 5):

We can using `issubset`

```
l=[set(x).issubset(dfb.id.tolist())for x in df['items']]
Out[64]: [True, False, False]
```

Then

```
df=df[l]
```

Answer (score 3):

You can define your custom function to search if all the elements of the list are in B dataframe and use it with [apply](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.apply.html).

Here `df1` is your Dataframe A and `df2` your Dataframe B:

```
sel = df1.apply(lambda x : all([i in df2['id'].unique() for i in x['items']]), axis=1)
finaldf = df1.loc[sel]
```

`finaldf` is:

```
         date            items
0  2019-06-05  [121, 123, 124]
```

Answer (score 2):

Valentino beat me to it, so the idea is the same:

```py
dataframe_a[dataframe_a['items'].apply(lambda lst: all(x in dataframe_b.id.values for x in lst))]
```

And here are a couple more words on your current approach:

- `pd.Series.isin` checks whether each element (in your case each list) exists **as a whole** in the other sequence. While your lists are unordered lists, for a series of tuples order would matter and checking for existence as a whole is the correct/expected behavior.
- Another issue is with calling `isin(dataframe_b.id)`, which is the same as calling `isin(dataframe_b.id.index)`. A pd.Series is like a dictionary and the `in`/contains property checks the loc/index (or keys in dictionary terminology), rather than the values themselves. If your loc/index contains ints that happen to overlap with your ids, `isin(dataframe_b.id)` could return *true* unexpectedly:

```py
In [17]: dataframe_b
Out[17]:
    id
0  121
1  122
2  123
3  124

In [18]: 121 in dataframe_b.id
Out[18]: False

In [19]: 121 in dataframe_b.id.index
Out[19]: False

In [20]: 121 in dataframe_b.id.values
Out[20]: True

In [21]: 1 in dataframe_b.id
Out[21]: True
```